# removing a element from ng-repeat only when checkbox is selected and console the removed value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I'm new to angular and in my problem I am able to remove the line when checkbox is selected, but I want to console the removed value

```
  var app = angular.module("appTable", []);
  app.controller("Allocation", function($scope) {

    $scope.dataList = [{
      name: 'lin',
      dept: 'b'
    }, {
      name: 'fie',
      dept: 'bbbb'
    }, {
      name: 'test',
      dept: 'aaa'
    }];
    $scope.add = function() {
      var data = {};
      data.name = '';
      data.dept = '';
      $scope.dataList.push(data);

    };
    $scope.remove = function() {
      var newDataList = [];
      angular.forEach($scope.dataList, function(v) {
        if (!v.isDelete) {
          newDataList.push(v);
        }
      });
      $scope.dataList = newDataList;
      console.log($scope.dataList)

    };
  });
```

I'm having trouble to console the removed value
https://jsfiddle.net/7g9na001/

Any help is appreciated. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just log the object content inside the remove handler like this.

**JS CODE:**

```
  $scope.remove = function() {
    var newDataList = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.dataList, function(v) {
        if (!v.isDelete) {
           newDataList.push(v);
        } else {
           //Value deleted from list
           console.log("Value being removed :" + JSON.stringify(v));
        }
    });
    $scope.dataList = newDataList;
    console.log($scope.dataList);
  };
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/7g9na001/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use *splice()* like below:

```
$scope.remove = function() {
    var deletedItems = [];
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.dataList.length; i++){
        if ($scope.dataList[i].isDelete) {
            deletedItems.push($scope.dataList.splice(i--, 1));
        }
    }
    console.log($scope.dataList, deletedItems);
};
```

Comment: Hey that works only when we select single checkbox element

Comment: I thought you call remove whenever a checkbox is clicked. I edited it to remove multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.remove = function() {
    var newDataList = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.dataList, function(v) {
      if (!v.isDelete) {
        newDataList.push(v);
      }else{
        console.log(v); //Here you can console the deleted values
      }
    });
    $scope.dataList = newDataList;
  };
```